# How can I tokenize a string and parse it into an array and read them

Tags: php, arrays

So, I want my page to read a txt file and then, tokenize it and create variables like an array.

For example:

My txt file:

```
Column1/Column2/Column3
A:K:Z
B:U:D
```

and then I want to read it like `$variable['0']['Column1']`;

Is there any way to do it?

```
<?php
    $handle = @fopen("info.txt", "r");
    if ($handle) {
        while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {

            $delimiters = ":";

            $token = strtok($buffer, $delimiters);
            $result = [];
            $row = [];
            $columns = ['rede', 'servidor', 'data', 'hora', 'usuarios', 'servidores'];
            while ($token){
                $row[$columns[count($row)]] = $token;
                if (count($row) == 6) { // write record
                    $result[] = $row;
                    $row = [];
                }
                $token = str_replace('\r', '', strtok($delimiters));
            }
            print_r($result);
        }
        if (!feof($handle)) {
            echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Are the column headers defined in the text document? Is that what the "Column1/Column2/Column3" is? Or are they defined in your code in `$columns`?

Comment: This was just an example. Because this code I tried to, but I couldn't reach what I want.

Comment: But, the columns should be defined in the PHP, $columns

Comment: The text file just has things separated by a :

Comment: We'd need to know the exact format specs in order to figure out edge cases. For instance, how does it escape literal `/` and `:`characters? Or, can you expect headers in the middle of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use `strtok`. I think it would be easier to just use `:` as the delimiter in `fgetcsv`. Something like this:

```
if ($handle) {
    $columns = ['rede', 'servidor', 'data', 'hora', 'usuarios', 'servidores'];
    while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ':')) !== false) {
        if (isset($row[5])) {
            $result[] = array_combine($columns, $row);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How could I get a value from the first line from column "servidor"?

Comment: Should be `$result[0]['servidor']`

Comment: It didn't work, actually, it creates an empty array.

Comment: `<?php
$handle = @fopen("info.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    $columns = ['rede', 'servidor', 'data', 'hora', 'usuarios', 'servidores'];
    while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ':')) !== false) {
        if (isset($row[5])) {
            $result[] = array_combine($columns, $row);
        }
    }
}

echo $result;

?>`

Comment: `sVipCHAT:IRC.jacksoow.Net:08/01/2019:19:24:51:499:80
sVipCHAT:IRC.NeoStats.Org:08/01/2019:19:25:49:500:80
`

Comment: It looks like some of the columns contain the delimiter?

Comment: What? I couldn't understand you.